Finding all $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(\,f(x)f(y) + y\,) = y\,f(x) + f(y - x + 1)$

Find all $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that, for any real $x, y$,
$$f(\,f(x)f(y) + y\,) = y\,f(x) + f(y - x + 1)$$

My approach:
Let $P(x, y)$ be the assertion.  Then,
$$P(x, 0) \implies f(f(x)\cdot f(0)) = f(1-x)$$
If $f(0) = 0$, then we get from the previous that $f \equiv 0$. Hence, we'll assume $f(0) \neq 0$.
Finding all linear solutions, we get that $f(x) = 1 - x$ or $f(x) = x - 1$ (and of course $f \equiv 0$ as well).
$$P(x, x) \implies f(f(x)^2 + x) = xf(x) + f(1)$$
so if $\exists a \in \mathbb{R} \ | \ f(a) = 0$ then taking $P(a, a)$ in the previous yields $f(a) = f(1) \implies f(1) = 0$.
For the continuation of this proof, I assumed that such an $a$ exists, however I was not able to prove so (which also means I was not able to prove $f(1) = 0$). If $f(1) = 0$, then $f(f(x)^2 + x) = xf(x)$.
Note that from $f(f(x)\cdot f(0)) = f(1-x)$, injectivity would solve the problem, since it implies $f$ linear. So I tried to prove injectivity next. Assume $f(a) = f(b)$ for real $a, b$. Then taking $P(b, a)$ in the given implies
$$f(f(a)\cdot f(b) + a) = af(b) + f(b - a + 1) \iff f(f(a)^2 + a) = af(a) + f(b - a + 1) \implies f(b - a + 1) = 0$$
So it would  suffice to prove that $x = 1$ is the only root of $f$, however I was not able to show this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Not a full answer, but I think i made some progress.
Claim 1: If there is $a\neq 1$ such that $f(a)=f(1)$, then $f(1)=0$
proof:
Consider $P(1,a)$. We get:
$$f(f(x)f(1)+1) = af(1) + f(b)$$
$$f(f(1)^{2}+1) = (a+1)f(1)$$
Using the known identity $f(f(x)^{2}+x)=xf(x)+f(1)$,
$$2f(1) = (a+1)f(1)$$
Which makes the claim obvious.
Claim 2: If some $a$ such that $f(a)=0$ exists, then $f(1)=0$
proof:
Consider $P(a,a)$. We get:
$$f(f(a)^{2} + a) = af(a) + f(1) \implies f(a) = f(1) \implies 0=f(1)$$
Which concludes the proof.
Claim 3: $f(1)=0$
FTSOC suppose $f(1)\neq 0$. Then, whatever the value of $f(1)$ is, it is unique, since by claim $1$, if $a\neq1$ existed such that $f(a)=f(1)$, we would have $f(1)=0$
Now, consider $P(0,0)$. This gives:
$$f(f(0)^{2}) = f(1)$$
Therefore by the uniqueness of $f(1)$, $f(0)^{2} = 1$ and $f(0) \in \lbrace -1, 1 \rbrace$
Now consider $P(y+1,y)$. We get:
$$f(f(y+1)f(y) + y) = yf(y+1) + f(0)$$
Taking $y=-1$, we get:
$$f(f(0)f(-1)+1) = -f(0) + f(0)$$
$$f(C) = 0$$
Where $C$ is some real number. From claim 2, this would mean we for sure know $f(1)=0$, which is a contradiction, since we assumed $f(1)\neq 0$, finishing our proof.
Claim 4: $f(0)=0$ if and only if $f\equiv 0$.
proof:
Take $P(x,0)$. This gives $f(f(x)f(0)) = f(1-x)$ which makes the claim obvious.
Claim 5: $f(f(x)^{2}+x) = xf(x)$.
Proof: Take $P(x,x)$ and use $f(1)=0$, which makes the claim obvious.
Claim 6: $f(x) = -f(2-x)$
Proof: Consider $P(x,1)$. We get:
$f(f(x)f(1)+1) = f(x) + f(1+1-x) \implies 0=f(x)+f(2-x) \implies -f(x)=f(2-x)$
As desired.
Ps: this also implies $f(1+x) = -f(1-x)$
Claim 7: If $f$ is an solution, so is $-f$.
Proof:
Notice that $(-f(x))\cdot(-f(y)) = f(x)f(y)$
So, taking
$$f(f(x)f(y)+y) = yf(x) + f(y-x+1)$$
and multiplying by -1 on both sides, we get:
$$-f((-f(x))(-f(y))+y) = y(-f(x)) + (-f(y-x+1))$$
Notice claims $6$ and $7$ together imply that
$$f(2-f(2-x)f(2-y)-y) = yf(2-x) + f(1+x-y)$$ [A]
Is valid for all $x,y$. Now, consider $P(x,2-y)$. We get:
$$f(f(x)f(2-y)+2-y) = (2-y)f(x) + f(3-x-y)$$
Using $-f(2-x)=f(x)$,
$$f(-f(2-x)f(2-y)+2-y) = (2-y)f(x) + f(3-x-y)$$ [B]
Notice the LHS of [A] and [B] are equal. So,
$$yf(2-x) + f(1+x-y) = 2f(x) - yf(x) + f(3-x-y)$$
Using $yf(2-x) = -yf(x)$,
$$f(1+x-y) = 2f(x) + f(3-x-y)$$
Picking $y=x$, we get:
$$f(1) = 2f(x) + f(3-2x) \implies f(x) = -\frac{f(3-2x)}{2}$$
$$2f(x) = f(2x-1)$$
$$f(x) -f(2-x) = f(2x-1)$$
$$f(x) = f(2x-1)+f(2-x)$$
Picking $x=0$, we get:
$f(1-y) = 2f(0) + f(3-y)$
That is, $f(1-y) = f(3-y)+2f(0)$
So, picking $y=y+1$,we get $f(1-(-y+1)) = f(3-(-y+1)) + 2f(0)$
$$f(y) = f(2+y) + 2f(0)$$
So,
$$f(-y)=f(2-y) + 2f(0) \implies f(-y) = -f(y) + f(-1) \implies f(y)+f(-y) = 2f(0)$$
Which means:
$$\frac{f(y)+f(-y)}{2}=f(0)$$ for all $y$

ps: Im not fully convinced the linear solutions are the only ones. I think there might be some pathological solutions at play here, but don't quote me on that

We show that $f(x)$ is injective unless $f(x)\equiv 0$.
Assume $f(a)=f(b)$ for some $a\neq b$. Now instead of taking $P(a,b)$, we can take both $P(a,x)$ and $P(b,x)$ to get
$$
f(f(x)f(a) + x) = xf(a) + f(x - a + 1)\\
f(f(b)f(x) + x) = xf(b) + f(x - b + 1).
$$
So
$$
f(x-a+1)=f(x-b+1)
$$
for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Let $x\mapsto x+a-1$ to get
$$f(x)=f(x+a-b).\tag{*}$$
Now from $P(x,a-b)$
$$
f(f(x)f(a - b) + a - b) = (a - b)f(x) + f(a - b - x + 1).
$$
Using (*) repeatedly gives
$$f(f(x)f(0)) = (a - b)f(x) + f(- x + 1).$$
However from $P(x,0)$ we also have
$$
f(f(x)f(0)) = f(-x + 1).
$$
Hence
$$
(a - b)f(x)=0.
$$
Since $a\neq b$ we have $f(x)\equiv 0$.
For remaining solutions (not identically zero) we have injectivity, then for example $P(x,0)$ gives
$$
f(f(x)f(0)) = f(-x + 1)\implies f(x)f(0) = -x + 1.
$$
Clearly $f(0)\neq 0$ and so $f(x)$ is linear, giving the remaining solutions $f(x)=x-1$ and $f(x)=-x+1$.

Thank you so much!
Im not even the OP, but I have been scratching my head at this for HOURS

I found the full solution myself as well (which has some resemblance to Sil's solution):
As previously mentioned, it suffices to prove injectivity. Therefore, assume $f(a) = f(b)$. Taking $P(a, x)$ and $P(b, x)$ gives
$$
f(f(a)\cdot f(x) + x) = xf(a) + f(x - a + 1) \\
f(f(b)\cdot f(x) + x) = xf(b) + f(x - b + 1)
$$
From which it follows that $f(x - a) = f(x - b)$ for all real $x$. Now, take $x = a, x = b$ to get $$f(0) = f(a - b) = f(b - a)$$
Claim: $f(k) = f(-k) \implies kf(k) = 0$.
Proof: From $f(x - a) =  f(x - b)$ if $f(a) = f(b)$, we get $f(x - k) = f(x + k)$ for $f(k) = f(-k)$.
Taking $x = f(k)^2$ gives $$f(f(k)^2 + k) = f(f(k)^2 - k)$$
Now, taking $P(k, k)$ and $P(-k, -k)$:
$$
f(f(k)^2 + k) = kf(k) + f(1) \\
f(f(-k)^2 - k) = -kf(-k) + f(1)
$$
But from the previous, this gives that $kf(k) = -kf(k) \iff kf(k) = 0 \ \  \square$
Now, since $f(a - b) = f(b - a) = f(-(a - b))$, we get
$$
(a-b)f(a-b) = 0
$$
So $a - b = 0$ or $f(a - b) = 0$. But $f(a - b) = 0 \implies f(0) = 0$, since $f(a - b) = f(0)$ (if $f(0) = 0$, $f$ is identically $0$). So we must have $a = b$, as required.
